# How to stop C# from buffering the data it sends through socket?

Tags: python, c#, sockets, tcp, buffer

I have been trying to send data through C# to Python using socket.
I tried to program the sender using Python to make sure everything is set up properly using the Python code be

```
import socket
import sys


HEADERSIZE = 10
raw_msg = "a"
print(f"{len(raw_msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}"+raw_msg)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1235))
s.listen(5)
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")

while True:


    raw_msg = input("input: ")

    msg = f"{len(raw_msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}"+raw_msg
    clientsocket.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))

    if raw_msg == "bye":
        break
    s.detach()
    s.close()
```

When the code is executed, the packages sent look like:

```
b'39        readEx'
b'cel|x,test_Purch'
b'ase_Forecast.xls'
b'x'
b'45        printD'
b'ataFrames|x,test'
b'_Purchase_Foreca'
b'st.xlsx'
```

So, I did it using C# using the code below:

```
 class Connection
    {
        int ServerPortNum;
        Socket connectionSocket;
        Socket welcomingSocket;

        public Connection() {
            ServerPortNum = 1235;
            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback,ServerPortNum);
            welcomingSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            welcomingSocket.NoDelay = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Starting");
            welcomingSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
            welcomingSocket.Listen(5);
        }

        public void Accept() {
            connectionSocket = welcomingSocket.Accept();
        }

        public void send(string raw_msg_string) 
        {   
            char[] lengthCharArray = raw_msg_string.Length.ToString().ToCharArray();
            string whiteSpace = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", 10-lengthCharArray.Length));
            string header = new string(lengthCharArray) + whiteSpace;

            Console.WriteLine(header + raw_msg_string);

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header + raw_msg_string);
            connectionSocket.Send(msg); 
        }

        public void ShutDown() {
            connectionSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);
            connectionSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            connectionSocket.Disconnect(false);
            connectionSocket.Close();
        }
    }
```

However the problem is C# is buffering the data it sends which is causing problems for my application. So, the send code for the same input looks like this:

```
b'39        readEx'
b'cel|x,test_Purch'
b'ase_Forecast.xls'
b'x45        print'
b'DataFrames|x,tes'
b't_Purchase_Forec'
b'ast.xlsx'
b''
```

So my question is, how can I prevent C# from buffering the data and cause it to send the package if the message is over instead of buffering it so that the packages look like the ones in python?

Comment: That's just how TCP works, it's a stream based protocol with no sense of "message" boundaries. If you expect some kind of correspondence between the pattern of sends/writes in your program and the packets on the wire then you are mistaken. You might consider UDP, but that also comes with extra work on your part to deal with the network problems that TCP is designed to overcome.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk so which protocol the Python code I provided is actually using and how can I recreate that in C#?

Comment: They're both using TCP. Firstly, the results are *almost* identical. Secondly, python specifically and socket APIs in general make no guarantees of deterministic behavior. The same data may result in the python program generating packets that look like those from the C# program, and the C# program generating packets that look like those of the python program.

Comment: The only guarantee TCP makes is the bytes sent are received in the same order. Buffer what you receive, use the first 10 bytes buffered as message size then extract that many bytes as the message.